# jQuery - triggering multiple events one by one

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery

I'm using jquery [tagsInput plugin](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/) where I need to dynamically modify the query(deleting the query or entering the new query) without actually typing in the search box connected with tagsInput plugin.

My problem here is I want to trigger **backspace event** at first then **enter event** next. Here is the code.

```
function triggering_events() {
    $(".tag").each(function() {
        var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e.keyCode = 8;
        e.which = 8;
        $("#input-search_tag").trigger(e); //triggering backspace event
    });
    var input = $("#input-search_tag");
    input.val("food");
    input.trigger(e); //triggering enter event
}
```

But only the backspace event is triggering from the above code. How can I make that enter event work?

Could anyone point out the mistake I've done?

Thanks!

Comment: is there a reason you're creating multiple events in a loop instead of just creating one and reusing it?

Comment: The reason is I'm a jQuery newbie :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try use the methods `removeTag` and `addTag` for remove and add tag's:

```
function triggering_events() {

    var 
        idInput = 'input-search',
        input = $("#" + idInput);

    $("#"+idInput+"_tagsinput .tag").each(function() {
        var tag = $.trim($(this).find('span:eq(0)').text());
        input.removeTag(tag);
    });

    input.addTag("food");
}
```

[run](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/KnwYf/)

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue here:

```
$("#input-search_tag").val("food").trigger(e); //triggering enter event
```

`.val()` returns you a string value of the jquery Element, it is not a chainable method. strings do not have a `trigger` method.

You could fix this by splitting it into two calls:

```
var input = $("#input-search_tag");
input.val("food");
input.trigger(e); // triggering enter event
```

Or using [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/):

```
$("#input-search_tag").val("food").end().trigger(e); //triggering enter event
```

Edit: putting it all together, along with reusing one event instead of creating multiples:

```
function triggering_events() {
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");

    e.which = 8;
    $(".tag").each(function() {
        $("#input-search_tag").trigger(e); // triggering backspace event
    });

    e.which = 13;
    $("#input-search_tag").val("food").end().trigger(e); // triggering enter event
}
```

Comment: I've tried it. Still the enter event is not triggering. I've updated my code, Please check it

Comment: @rnk your fix for the multiple events is not correct. I will edit my answer to include the correct fix.

Comment: @jbabey, you said  `$("#input-search_tag").val("food").trigger(e)` will cause an error, but it won't, as per the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/) this is not a problem here, as it is used as a setter, instead of getter. (see [demo](http://jsbin.com/equjuc/1))